# Meaning of the asterisk symbol in Java

Tags: java, variables

Is it possible to change the meaning of the asterisk symbol (multiplication operator) in Java?

I want to do this:

```
int ex = 600 * 0.98;
```

It fails because you can't convert from double to int.  Can I make it so that I'm able to convert the double to an integer? Or does the
asterisk only have one meaning that can't be changed?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Do you want to store `*` in a variable, and use it? If yes, Why on earth would you want to do that?

Comment: What do you mean? ints are just numbers. They can't have asterisks in them.

Comment: Multiplication is the only possible meaning of `*` in this context.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Could you explain what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3):

> I just want the OPERATION in math, not a string.

To have an operation, you must have code.  One way of doing this is to have a method like

```
public static double ex(double factor) {
    return factor * 0.98;
}
```

or if the factor is a field

```
private double factor = 600;

public double ex() {
    return factor * 98 / 100;
}

public static void main(String... ignored)  {
    Main m = new Main();
    System.out.println("factor: "+m.factor+" ex: "+ m.ex());
    m.factor = 700;
    System.out.println("factor: "+m.factor+" ex: "+ m.ex());
}
```

prints

```
factor: 600.0 ex: 588.0
factor: 700.0 ex: 686.0
```

As you can see `ex()` is re-evaluated each time it is used.

Why do I `* 98 / 100`? I do this as each value can be represented exactly however 0.98 is not represent exactly and can have a small error.

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(0.98));
```

prints the closest representable value to 0.98

```
0.979999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875
```

---

If you want to store text you need to do something like

```
String ex = "600 * 0.98";
```

An `int` value is for storing a whole number which is a 32-bit signed value, nothing else.

Comment: I meant if how to have the operator asterisk like in real math, not the word, my question was how to have an asterisk operation.

Comment: @Mattcejpa It's really not clear what you want. What do you mean by an "asterisk operation", considering that in the question you say you don't want multiplication? What should the variable `ex` contain as a result?

Comment: @Juhana i want to have friction in my game, so if i have a variable asterisk 0.98 it would have the finishing operation. In math class they have question like 100 * 1 or something. I just want the OPERATION in math, not a string.

Comment: @Mattcejpa: If you just want the calculation and not the result, then `anything * anything else` won't work.  You'll need an object containing a function that does the calculation and returns the result.  There's no way to redefine `*` to do something other than what it does -- and what it does, is multiply two numbers right then and there.

Comment: @Mattcejpa See my updated answer above.  A variable has a fixed value but a method can return a different value each time it is used based on a formula.

Answer (score 0):

Uhhh.

The short answer is that you can't do that. A variable of type `int` can only store an integer value. The expression you assign to the int has to evaluate to an integer.

What integer value do you want assigned to ex?

```
int ex = 588;  // 600 * 0.98
```

What meaning are you associating with the asterisk between two numeric values that is not multiplication?

If you want to store an array of characters, then:

```
char[] ex = "600 * 0.98".toCharArray();
```